# How do you fold code by indentation in sublime 3?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, folding

In atom, the below is what you use to fold code by indent levels, but how do you do this in sublime?

Ctrl+k, then Ctrl+1 ... 9   Fold all code at indent level 1 ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same:
`Ctrl + K, Ctrl + 1` to fold all code on indent 1.

To unfold all `Ctrl + K, Ctrl + J`.

Same procedure all the way to indent 9 (`Ctrl + K, Ctrl + <number>`). You can also fold by clicking on the side line number arrow:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`CMD/CTRL + K, CMD/CTRL + <number>`

for example, on MacOS, to fold to indent-level-1: `CMD+K, CMD+1`

Using menus: On MacOS: `Edit > Code Folding > <level>`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes code folding doesn't seem to work in Sublime3 especially if you've installed some package which have conflicts. You can try via the menu on MacOS: `Edit > Code Folding > <level>` to override or create your own key bindings via `Sublime Text 3 -> Preferences -> Key Bindings` and add something like the below. I've tried to replicate some of the key bindings from Intellij in the below settings, you can configure them as per your liking.

```
[{ "keys": ["super+shift+minus"], "command": "fold" },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+plus"], "command": "unfold" },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+1"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 1} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+2"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 2} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+3"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 3} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+4"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 4} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+5"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 5} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+6"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 6} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+7"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 7} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+8"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 8} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+9"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 9} },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+0"], "command": "unfold_all" },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+j"], "command": "unfold_all" },
  { "keys": ["super+shift+t"], "command": "fold_tag_attributes" },
]
```